# Array to Hash or 2 binary element Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

**I'm seeking the most concise way to do this**

Given the following Array:

```
['a','b','c']
```

how to get this:

```
{'a'=> 1,'b'=> 2, 'c'=> 3}
```

and

```
[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]
```

I have few solutions at mind, just want to see yours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.zip(1..a.length)
```

and

```
Hash[a.zip(1..a.length)]
```

Comment: No, both of these raise "can't convert Range into Array" as written. You have to do "a.zip((1..a.size).to_a)" for the first one, and this then raises "odd number of arguments for Hash" in the second one, so you have to do Hash[*...flatten].

Answer (score 2):

```
# 1.8.7+:
['a','b','c'].each_with_index.collect {|x,i| [x, i+1]} # => [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
# pre-1.8.7:
['a','b','c'].enum_with_index.collect {|x,i| [x, i+1]}

# 1.8.7+:
Hash[['a','b','c'].each_with_index.collect {|x,i| [x, i+1]}] # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
# pre-1.8.7:
Hash[*['a','b','c'].enum_with_index.collect {|x,i| [x, i+1]}.flatten]
```

Comment: When was "enum_with_index" introduced? It doesn't exist in 1.8.5!

Answer (score 1):

If you want concise and fast, and 1.8.5 compatability, this is the best I've figured out:

```
i=0
h={}
a.each {|x| h[x]=i+=1}
```

The version of Martin's that works in 1.8.5 is:

```
Hash[*a.zip((1..a.size).to_a).flatten]
```

But this is 2.5x slower than the above version.

Answer (score 0):

```
aa=['a','b','c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]    #Anyone explain Why it became double quote here??

aa.map {|x| [x,aa.index(x)]}   #assume no duplicate element in array
=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]]

Hash[*aa.map {|x| [x,aa.index(x)]}.flatten]
=> {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}
```

Comment: "#Anyone explain Why it became double quote here??" - would you expect Ruby to remember whether the string was originally created using single or double quotes?